# write text files in pythran fails

Tags: python, pythran

I'm working with pythran, a Python to c++ compiler http://pythran.readthedocs.io/

In its manual page, [pythran says it supports the method `write` from `TextIOWrapper`](https://pythran.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SUPPORT.html#io)

However, trying to compile this simple file

file: `mylib.py`

```
#pythran export write_test(str,bool)
#pythran export fake_write(str)

def write_test(fname,r):
    if r:
        print('writing %s'%fname)
        f = open(fname,'w')
        #write_line = f.writelines
        write_line = f.write
    else:
        print('NO FILE WILL BE WRITTEN')
        write_line = fake_write
    for i in range(10):
        write_line(str(i) + '\n')
    if r:
        f.close()

def fake_write(s):
    return 0
```

with the command line

> pythran mylib.py -o mylib.so -O3 -march=native -v

fails with the message:

> mylib.py:9:21 error: Unsupported attribute 'write' for this object

Pythran version: `0.9.8.post2`

Python version: `3.8.5`

Using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the current version of pythran. It was fixed in the development version of pythran (0.9.9.dev).

Instead of using a pointer to the `f.write` function, we can define a `lambda` with no return that does the job and solves the problem:

```
#pythran export write_test(str,bool)
#pythran export fake_write(str)

def write_test(fname,r):
    if r:
        print('writing %s'%fname)
        f = open(fname,'w')
        #write_line = f.writelines
        write_line = lambda s: f.write(s)
    else:
        print('NO FILE WILL BE WRITTEN')
        write_line = fake_write
    for i in range(10):
        write_line(str(i) + '\n')
    if r:
        f.close()

def fake_write(s):
    return None
```

this modification was advised by the developers in their [github bug report page](https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran/issues/1699).